# Python: Mainwindow closes when pushbutton is pressed

Tags: python

There is a mainwindow.py file that creates the Ui_MainWindow class (main window). There is a file called Myapp.py, which creates a subclass of the MainWindowUIClass class of the Ui_MainWindow class from which the main window should be called. When Myapp.py starts, the window is called. But when pressed, the button closes with the message aborted (disconnected). Please help me figure out why this is happening.

Mainwindow.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow-2.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot


class Ui_MainWindow(QObject):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.widget)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(583, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browseSlot)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.writeDocSlot)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.returnedPressedSlot)        
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "KSERVICE"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "File Name"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Write Doc"))
        
    @pyqtSlot( )
    def returnedPressedSlot(self):
            pass
   
    @pyqtSlot( )
    def writeDocSlot(self):
           pass
   
    @pyqtSlot( )
    def browseSlot(self):
           pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

MyApp.py code:

```
# MyApp.py
## D. Thiebaut
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from mainwindow2 import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class MainWindowUIClass(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the super class
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, MW):
        # Setup the UI of the super class, and add here code
        # that relates to the way we want our UI to operate.
        super().setupUi(MW)
        # close the lower part of the splitter to hide the 
        # debug window under normal operations
        self.splitter.setSizes([300, 0])

    def debugPrint(self, msg):
        # Print the message in the text edit at the bottom of the
        # horizontal splitter
        self.debugTextBrowser.append(msg)

    # slot
    def returnPressedSlot(self):
        # Called when the user enters a string in the line edit and
        # presses the ENTER key.
        self.debugPrint("RETURN key pressed in LineEdit widget")

    # slot
    def writeDocSlot(self):
        # Called when the user presses the Write-Doc button.
        self.debugPrint("Write-Doc button pressed")

    # slot
    def browseSlot(self):
        # Called when the user presses the Browse button
        self.debugPrint("Browse button pressed")

def main():
    # This is the MAIN ENTRY POINT of our application.  The code at the end
    # of the mainwindow.py script will not be executed, since this script 
    # is now our main program.   We have copied the code from mainwindow.py
    # here since it was automatically generated by pyuic5    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindowUIClass()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```